# How to get Azure sign-ins by user group with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a list of user logins by security/user group for the past 30 days, I had a look at Azure Sign-ins audit I can only filter by IP, Username one at a time, wanted to know if there is a way to filter by group or if there is powershell script to filter logins over 30 day period for all users in a specific user group.

I tried using Azure sign-ins but can only filter per user and want to by user group, I have powershell script to list all users in the group but need to be able to see successful log ins for each users over the past 30 days

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following Powershell script :

Before running the script, you need to have permissions to query groups and group members and read the users.

For that purpose I created an app with all the required permissions,
like User.Read.All, Group.Read.All, GroupMember.Read.All application permissions, when using AppId.

[image]

Now that the app has required permissions, Use the app Id to query the sign-in logs within 30 days of users of particular group using below script.

PowerShell:

```
$groupusers=Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<groupObjectId>"
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString('o')
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString('o')


foreach($userMember in $groupusers)
{
    $userDN = $userMember.DisplayName    
    $logs= Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq 'xxx'and createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate and userDisplayName eq '$userDN'"
    $logs | select UserDisplayName,createdDateTime
}
```

Response:

```
UserDisplayName CreatedDateTime     
--------------- ---------------     
 User 1       2023-03-28T10:16:25Z
 User 2       2023-03-28T10:10:53Z
 User 1       2023-03-28T10:09:38Z
 User 1       2023-03-28T09:21:46Z
 User 2       2023-03-28T09:13:46Z
 User 2       2023-03-28T09:13:25Z
 User 1       2023-03-28T09:13:17Z
 User 1       2023-03-28T09:13:13Z
 User 3       2023-03-28T10:16:25Z
```

[image]

- $logs  //use this to query all properties

Code:

```
foreach($userMember in $groupusers)
{
    $userDN = $userMember.DisplayName   
    $logs= Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq 'appId'and createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate and userDisplayName eq '$userDN'"
    $logs
    $logs | select UserDisplayName,createdDateTime
}
```

Response:

[image]

```
Id                               : xxx
CreatedDateTime                  : 2023-03-28T09:13:13Z
UserDisplayName                  : MT User 1
UserPrincipalName                : xxxx
UserId                           : xxx06
AppId                            : xxx
AppDisplayName                   : appname
IpAddress                        : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ClientAppUsed                    : Browser
CorrelationId                    : 4fx7dxx
ConditionalAccessStatus          : notApplied
OriginalRequestId                : c1exxx1
IsInteractive                    : True
TokenIssuerName                  : 
TokenIssuerType                  : AzureAD
ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds     : 157
RiskDetail                       : none
RiskLevelAggregated              : none
RiskLevelDuringSignIn            : none
RiskState                        : none
RiskEventTypes                   : 
ResourceDisplayName              : Microsoft Graph
ResourceId                       : 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
AuthenticationMethodsUsed        : {}
Status                           : class SignInStatus {
                                     ErrorCode: 50140
                                     FailureReason: This occurred due to 'Keep me signed in' interrupt when the user was signing in.
                                     AdditionalDetails: This is an expected part of the login flow, where a user is asked if they want to remain signed into this browser to make 
                                   further logins easier. For more details, see 
                                   https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/The-new-Azure-AD-sign-in-and-Keep-me-signed-in-experiences/td-p/xxx
                                   }
                                   
DeviceDetail                     : class SignInAuditLogObjectDeviceDetail {
                                     DeviceId: 
                                     DisplayName: 
                                     OperatingSystem: xx
                                     Browser: xx
                                     IsCompliant: False
                                     IsManaged: False
                                     TrustType: 
                                   }
                                   
Location                         : class SignInAuditLogObjectLocation {
                                     City: Lalapet
                                     State: Telangana
                                     CountryOrRegion: IN
                                   }
                                   
MfaDetail                        : 
AppliedConditionalAccessPolicies : {}
AuthenticationProcessingDetails  : {class AdditionalDetail {
                                     Key: Root Key Type
                                     Value: Unknown
                                   }
                                   }
NetworkLocationDetails           : {}

UserDisplayName :  User 1
CreatedDateTime : 2023-03-28T10:16:25Z

UserDisplayName : User 1
CreatedDateTime : 2023-03-28T10:10:53Z

UserDisplayName : User 1
CreatedDateTime : 2023-03-28T10:09:38Z
```

If need , This can be done for all groups as below:

```
$AllGroups=Get-AzureADGroup
foreach($group in $AllGroups )
{
    
$groupObj=$group.ObjectId   
$groupusers=Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "$groupObj"
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString('o')
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString('o')


foreach($userMember in $groupusers)
{
$userDN = $userMember.DisplayName

$logs= Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq 'xxx'and createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate and userDisplayName eq '$userDN'"
write-host "Users belonging to group : " $group.DisplayName
write-host "  "
$logs | select UserDisplayName,createdDateTime

write-host " "

write-host "========= "
}
}
```

[image]

**References:**

1. [Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs (AzureADPreview) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditsigninlogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)
2. [Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets for reporting - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-powershell-reporting#sign-in-logs)

Comment: I created the App with the API permissions, when I run your script with my group ID and application ID, I recieve the following message

Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs : Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs 
Code: UnknownError
Message: Too Many Requests
InnerError:
RequestId: 
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 11:16:14 GMT
HttpStatusCode: 429
HttpStatusDescription: 
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:6 char:12
$logs= Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq 'b4 ...
Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.GetAuditSignInLog

Comment: It must be used with AzureAdPreview and try filtering top 5 or 10 to check if its working. It must be because of many users.